# Matlab - Digital Image processors

Tags: matlab

I have question about how I can detect the leakage in oil and gas pipeline by using matlab.Like if we have image token above pipeline and by using matlab we need to see if their any leakage on this pipeline or not.

Regards.

Comment: Can you upload an example image to the question? In image processing, solutions to different problems may have different approaches.

Comment: there is some issue when I upload image or files.

Comment: I suppose what you call an issue is that it permits you to have a link to the uploaded image instead of displaying it. This is because you are a newcomer and the site allows you to display images after gaining some reputation. A link will be sufficient though.